# SRAM/DRAM Price Difference

Tags: cmos, memory

An SRAM cell uses 6 CMOS transistors to store 1 bit of information. A DRAM cell uses 1 transistor and 1 capacitor to store a bit. So one could guess that for the same amount of information (say, 1GB), SRAM would be around 6 times more expensive than DRAM (if capacitors were free). In the real world, however, this difference seems to be **much** larger than a factor of 6. What's the reason for that?

Comment: Economies of scale? And cost of packaging doesn't change much.

Comment: What’s the problem with producing large amount of SRAM?

Comment: Who is going to buy it?

Comment: Wouldn’t it be more convenient to use SRAM as a computer RAM instead of DRAM (yes, it will be ~5 times more expensive, but it will be faster and more power-efficient)

Comment: Convenient only for the designer. End user doesn't care. Cost is a big factor. SRAM is not more power efficient if you are running at comparably high speeds.

Comment: @DKNguyen So you are basically saying that a 5-times price difference made the demand for SRAM so tiny that nobody bothers producing it in large quantities?

Comment: SRAM *is* used, in the closest caches, in MCUs, etc.  One could argue that the a register file, and even pipeline registers, are forms of SRAM.  But yes, most applications of what the general public thinks of as "computers" benefit from having immense amounts of "good enough" memory strategically fronted by a tiny bit of "really awesome" memory which proxies for it in key places.

Comment: @Mr_Tusk For external memory, yes. SRAM is the more important of the two, but also the less visible of the two.

Comment: It's a minor corner on a chip to handle the refresh and makes no practical difference to performance. And at many times the cost, the mass market simply isn't there, so it's a niche boutique item, still useful for some purposes (eg. memory on a digital oscilloscope or part of an FPGA) but it's not going to be in consideration for mass memory in a PC.

Comment: Why is it more expensive to buy a bare OEM hard drive than the same hard drive from the same manufacturer in an USB case?

Comment: 1Mx16 DRAM 50ns $NZ$10.31 https://nz.element14.com/integrated-silicon-solution-issi/is41lv16105d-50tli/dram-16mbit-tsop-ii-44/dp/2901162?ost=IS41LV16105D-50TLI 1Mx16 SRAM 45ns NZ$16.54 https://nz.element14.com/cypress-semiconductor/cy62167ev30ll-45bvxit/sram-16mbit-40-to-85deg-c/dp/2908570?ost=CY62167EV30LL-45BVXIT

Comment: Premature optimization is the root of all evil!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So one could guess that for the same amount of information (say, 1GB), SRAM would be around 6 times more expensive than DRAM (if capacitors were free).

Actually, making the capacitor is the hard part.

> In the real world, however, this difference seems to be much larger than a factor of 6. What's the reason for that?

SRAM itself isn't that expensive when it's made at high volumes. Go buy a few hundred dollar GPU and you're getting a lot of SRAM, in some cases more than 100MB worth ... as well as thousands of graphics cores and gigabytes of GDDR.  Factor in the fraction of the die that is actually SRAM (not that much) and the fraction of the cost that is the die and you aren't paying that much per MB of SRAM.

But if you're looking at discrete 512 Mbit SRAMs (rather than a similar amount of SRAM integrated into a GPU or similar mass market product), that's an extreme niche part made in tiny volumes and priced accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

SRAM uses 6 transistors to form a gated and buffered RS latch. No bit storage capacitor is used. Yet SRAM consumes space in its complexity per bit storage. As fast as SRAM can be, it is not density friendly, so mass data buffers need to be DRAM, until FRAM catches up.

DRAM is 1 transistor in a latch with a capacitor to retain state, but each cell needs to refresh its memory about 16 times per second, or risk loosing data. Hence DRAM has its own memory controller that handles the background details of refresh, read and write cycles, etc. Even so DRAM has much more memory density then SRAM.

This is where market pricing dictates the large gap in price per byte of storage. I recently paid $110 USD for 32 GB of DDRAM. This paragraph from  [this website](https://www.diffen.com/difference/Dynamic_random-access_memory_vs_Static_random-access_memory#:%7E:text=power%20as%20DRAM.-,Price,DRAM%20costs%20%2420%2D%2475.) (https://www.diffen.com) explains some of the issues for cost:

> **Price**
>
> SRAM is much more expensive than DRAM. A gigabyte of SRAM cache costs
> around $5000, while a gigabyte of DRAM costs $20-$75. Since SRAM uses
> flip-flops, which can be made of up to 6 transistors, SRAM needs more
> transistors to store 1 bit than DRAM does, which only uses a single
> transistor and capacitor. Thus, for the same amount of memory, SRAM
> requires a higher number of transistors, which increases the
> production cost.

SRAM is still widely used due to its fast read/write speeds, and power-down options. It is used as temporary data buffers that hold 4 KB to 64 KB (or more) blocks of data as they move from DRAM to/from USB thumb drives, Ethernet packets, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The cost isn't really the transistor itself, it's how much the design takes space on the wafer when it's manufactured or if it has any yield issues.

Also adding a capacitor might require different type of a wafer (thickness) or more complicated process.

Only the manufacturers would know the exact details on the cost structure.